# mkdir command inside shell script problem

Tags: linux, bash, shell, sh

I have created the below shell script to create directories in a sequence based on user input
where I get the name of the directory with the start and end number to create multiple directories

I am trying to achieve the results of `mkdir sample{1..10}`

```
name=$1
start=$2
end=$3

mkdir $name{$start..$end}
```

`./script.sh movie 1 10`

When I run the below ls command to list the directories

`ls -lrt`

```
Expected Output:
movie1
movie2
movie3
...
```

Actual output

`movie{1..10}`

Why this script is not creating multiple directories

Comment: echo $(eval "echo $name{$start..$end}")